# Is it possible to stop SonarQube displaying effort figures for debt and remediation effort?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.5

SonarQube displays estimates for the amount of effort required to fix issues in various locations.

Certain types of manager instantly home in on these figures as they appear to give an easy answer to the difficult and nuanced questions.

It would be easier to have constructive conversations if SonarQube did not attempt to put a figure on the debt.

Is it possible to somehow stop SonarQube from displaying these figures?

Comment: IMO this is more a relationship problem with your manager, you can remind him that people developing the tool are humans being and are, like everyone else, likely to get things wrong from time to time and so the tool as to be taken for what it is : a tool that gives valuable information, not an oracle (no pun intended).

Comment: @benzonico Yes it's a meat space problem, but the tool is making it worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, no. This is a core feature.

The closest you could come is with the commercial Governance plugin (to be released with 5.6) which would allow you to set the remediation cost for each rule to 0min.

Comment: It might be a core feature, but if other users also find it creates more problems than it solves would you consider providing a way to switch it off?

Comment: That's a big 'if' @henry. I used to have a friend who said "let's burn that bridge when we come to it"